# Appcelerator/Titanium Holo UI in case of modal: true is not working

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, android

I have problem with UI.

I change default UI into Holo with changin tiapp.xml:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<tool-api-level>14</tool-api-level>
<manifest>
    <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <activity android:name=".ThemetestActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
</android>
```

Holo UI works fine. But if i open new window with prop model: ture, new window opens with old UI, not holo. But if modal false, it works fine (but back button not works. I use modal: ture, because i need back button to work).

This is my code:

```
var myButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
   title: 'Test button',
   width: 500,
   height: 100,
   top: 60,
   font: { fontSize: 30 }
});

table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        title:'Flight Details',
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        backButtonTitle: 'Back',
        modal: true
    });

   window.add(myButton);
    window.open( { animated: true } );
});
```

Why new windows is not in Holo UI?

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the answer on the Titanium Q&A dev site:

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/158711/holo-ui-in-case-of-modal-true-is-not-working#answer-270378

```
In tiapp.xml please add the following for applying holo theme on modal windows :
<activity 
  android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiModalActivity" 
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" />
```

Comment: I see this already. This is my question too :) I posted my question in forum and here at the same moment :)